# Find a pair of elements from an given array whose sum equals a specific target number in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

In Javascript is any other efficient way to achieve this task?

I tried as:

```
const a1 = [1,3,4,2,5,7,8,6];
var newArray =[];

function fun(a,n){      

for(let i = 0; i<a.length; i++){
 for(let j=i+1; j<a.length; j++){        
   if((a[i]+a[j])==n){        
     newArray.push([a[i],a[j]]);       
    }
  }
 }
}     

fun(a1, 10)
console.log(newArray);
```

Here output:

```
[(3,7),(4,6),(2,8)]
```

Comment: Very broad question.  But if I had to make a suggestion I would say sort the array first, and then work from both ends towards the middle

Answer (score 0):

The question is tagged javascript, but this answer is basically language agnostic.

If the array is sorted (or you can sort it), you can iterate over the array and for each element x in it binary search for (target-x) in the array. This gives you O(nlogn) run time.

If you can use extra memory, you can populate a dictionary with the elements of the array, and then for each element x in the array, look up the dictionary for (target-x). If your dictionary is implemented on a hashtable, this gives you O(n) run time.

Comment: Thanks but can you elaborate more by writing JS code.

Answer (score 0):

I think your method makes sense from a brute force perspective.

In terms of optimization, a few things come to mind.

1. Do duplicates count? If not, you can remove all duplicates from
   the starting lists.
2. You can sort the lists in ascending order,
   and skip the remainder of the inner loop when the sum exceeds the
   target value.

Answer (score 0):

This is a general programming problem commonly referred to as the "two sum problem", which itself is a subset of the [subset sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem).
But nevertheless can be solved efficiently and I used [this article](https://coderbyte.com/algorithm/two-sum-problem) as inspiration.

```js
const a1 = [1, 3, 4, 2, 5, 7, 8, 6];

// our two sum function which will return
// all pairs in the array that sum up to S
function twoSum(arr, S) {

  const sums = [];
  const hashMap = new Map();

  // check each element in array
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

    // calculate S - current element
    let sumMinusElement = S - arr[i];

    // check if this number exists in hash map
    // if so then we found a pair of numbers that sum to S
    if (hashMap.has(sumMinusElement.toString())) {
      sums.push([arr[i], sumMinusElement]);
    }

    // add the current number to the hash map
    hashMap.set(arr[i].toString(), arr[i])
  }

  // return all pairs of integers that sum to S
  return sums;
}

console.log(twoSum(a1, 10))
```

Here I use the [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) object since I think it's faster when checking if number already exists, but I might be wrong and you can use just a plain object, as in the article, if you want.